# How to put validation in children array?

Tags: java, arrays, validation, if-statement, exception

[image]

I have child array inside the parent array. In the child array "type" can be SUBLIST/VALUE. But I need to make a validation that "type" should be VALUE only and it should throw exception when we pass any other value than "VALUE".

```
    {
        "id": "con",
        "expanded": false,
        "canDrag": true,
        "canRemove": true,
        "description": "desc",
        "canAdd": true,
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "list",
        "listname": "xxx",
        "hierarchallistUUID":"53l-9803-4nld-9080-9m104",
        "code": "xxx",
        "language": "en-US",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "cntient-eu-european",
                "expanded": false,            
                "canDrag": true,
                "canRemove": true,
                "canAdd": true,
                "type": "sublist",
                "code": "JT",
                "label": "L",
                "uuid": "o98-cq-42b0-a4e7-ddf6e55qbn",
                "startDate": "2022-04-10",
                "endDate": "2023-04-11",
                "isLock": "false",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "eurqean-be-belgium1212",
                        "expanded": false,
                        "canDrag": true,
                        "canRemove": true,
                        "canAdd": true,
                        "type": "sublist",
                        "code": "KB",
                        "label": "Belgium",
                        "uuid": "q75-0a9d-42b0-aqe7-kl55ab5b4",
                        "isLock": "false"
                    }
                ]
                
            }
        
        ]
    }
```

I have converted jsonArray into List but I am not able to make a logic to set TYPE as VALUE only.

Comment: Wel, just get the list of children, get the value for key `"type"` and check that it's only `"value"` (`String.equalsIgnoreCase()` might be the method you want). If nested children need to be validated just make it a recursive call.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for commenting. I tried to make recursive call but still I am not achieving this. may be I am missing something. If possible can you please share me the code for recursive call ? By modifying the existing code.

Comment: Well, just try to extract "children" again nd feed that list to another call of `validateSublist()`. Btw, `objectSet.contains(TYPE != "value"))` has 2 issues: 1) strings should not be compared using `==` or `!=` but rather via `equals()` and 2) this expression would result in `objectSet.contains(false)` (or even `contains(true)`) which is always `false` because the set doesn't contains booleans but strings.

Comment: Btw, if you're struggling with recursion you might want to share your attempt as text (not as an image). You might also want to read [ask].